# Including an Icon inside the <input> tag

Tags: html, css

```css
.Main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

// css to show the navigation bar top and the image of westminister
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font: italic bold 50px Georgia, serif;
}

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topnavbar {
  text-align: right;
  font: size 19px;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#searchbar {
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration-color: #ffffff;
  font: size 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
  background: #2f3640;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 150px;
}

.search-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4da6ff;
  outline: none;
}
```

I'm trying to make this web application using AngularJS and I am fairly new to it. I am making a navigation bar for a page to start with and I think I have done the normal bar properly. However I want to also add a search bar (haven't done the functioning yet since I have no idea how to) which will appeal when the mouse hovers over the `<a>` tag . I'm referring to a video which will be linked below. The difference is he is not using  a navigation bar instead doing it in the middle of the video

The css and html is shown below.

The video I am referring to is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1PeTDrw6OY

PS: what I want to do is include the icon inside the gray padding area so I can set the padding to zero and it would have the icon inside the padding alone and on hover I could expand the search bar field and let the user type. Any input regarding this is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Consider adding both input tag and button inside one <li> this will give your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a common parent element to make it easier on yourself. With your HTML the most straightforward way would be to include the `<a>` into the `<li>`, instead of having it after. So turn this

```
<li><input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Here"> </li>
<a class="search-btn" href="#"> <i id="btn" class="fas fa-search"></i> </a>
```

Into this:

```
<li>
    <input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Here"> 
    <a class="search-btn" href="#"> <i id="btn" class="fa fa-search"></i> </a>
</li>
```

Then you can use `position: absolute` and easily place the icon where you want by adding this CSS:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li input + a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; /* change this */
    left: 5px; /* change this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `search-bar` class, you can get what you want

```css
.Main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

// css to show the navigation bar top and the image of westminister
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font: italic bold 50px Georgia, serif;
}

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topnavbar {
  text-align: right;
  font: size 19px;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#searchbar {
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration-color: #ffffff;
  font: size 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: right;
  background: #2f3640;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 150px;
}

.search-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 38px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4da6ff;
  outline: none;
}

.search-bar{

     position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="Main">
  <div id="navbar">



    <ul>
      <li><img src="assets/img/xyz.png" alt="logo" width="180px" height="80px" style="float:left"></li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar active" [routerLink]="['page6']">Display Items </a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page2']">Add Items </a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page3']"> Delete Items </a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page4']">Borrow Items </a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page5']">Return Items</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page6']">Generate Report </a> </li>
      <li> <a class="topnavbar" [routerLink]="['page6']">Generate Report </a> </li>
      <li>
       <div class="search-bar">
         <input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Here">  
            <button class="search-btn"><i id="btn" class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </li>
     






    </ul>




  </div>



</div>
```